# Searching Deep Fritz 14 Database

Tags: fritz

So I just got Deep Fritz 14. This is my first "real chess program." I know Deep Fritz probably wasn't the best choice for a first program, but it's what I got. I've been trying to learn how to use it by just poking around and testing things out. By doing this, I found the game database. I thought it might be a great way to study games of famous (or not so famous) players to improve my own skills. However, there seems to be no way to search through the database for a particular player or opening. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Also, probably best for another question, but can someone link some tutorials to Deep Fritz 14?

Comment: I had Fritz 12. I remember there was a search dialog where I could enter anything like a player's name. Check the menu, it has to be somewhere.

Comment: Well, there's a "Filter Games" button, but it doesn't seem to do anything when I click it.

Comment: Welcome to chess stack, +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can see help menu for user manual. Or you can see this [link](https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqjLq6tbXKAhVDjCwKHUNnC8cQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fshop.chessbase.com%2Fdownload%2FProgramme%2FDeepFritz13%2FDeepFritz13Manual.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEdZnASxKE-GNyX6nfjhXasBXL1Sw&bvm=bv.112064104,d.bGg) for a more detailed manual, written for Fritz 13, but there is no difference at all. Engines are changing but GUIs are almost the same.

Comment: All the manual says about the filter games button is that it exists (no surprise) and that the keyboard shortcut is Ctrl-F, which I have already tried and produces the same result as clicking it: nothing.

Comment: I used Fritz GUI before, and Im sure there is a button for searching database. You should look more carefully.

Comment: There is. It just doesn't do anything when I click it, as I mentioned above (under the original question).

Comment: Then maybe your question is related to super user.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3CL8WWd83Q&list=PLRziwL2_NOku7UokUz3_obokoo_qgQK6U&index=12 explains how to filter games from the database screen.
http://steamcommunity.com/app/276750/discussions/0/522730699421109355/ is people with the same question.  Chessbase claims that there is no manual.

I only have chessbase 10 so the interface is different.  There is a menu item under Edit, Find Position.  THe catch-all answer for every software problem, reinstall and see if that works.

Get similar people together and demand that Chessbase writes a patch to fix their product.
http://en.chessbase.com/pages/download for just the reader without fritz.

Answer (score 0):

I have been often in your situation. I hate to read reams of pages explanations before getting to the point. I don't have the time nor the patience. I am often frustrated by my attempts in figuring out by exploring on my own, the interface, IMHO, is not friendly. However, for the case in point I may have been lucky and I hope this will help you.

I wanted to search for a certain board position in my database. I used the command filter games as follows:

1. Open one game with that position or otherwise create that position on the board,
2. Assuming you opened that position in a game, you are now in the Home menu; click Copy Position,
3. Now go back to the database where you are doing the search and click Filter Games,
4. Click Position in that window and the click Copy board, now you have that position in the Filter Games window
5. Click OK 
   A list of all the games in the given database having that position will appear.

I hope this is useful. Happy 2018 everyone!